# Views in circle with animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, trigonometry

What I've to do is to lay out few UIButtons circularly and whenever any button is tapped that button should animate to the top position(top of the circle, i.e. first button in the circle) and hence all the other buttons should animate appropriately so that the tapped button comes to the top.
Now, I've arranged the buttons circularly using

```
double perAngle = 2 * M_PI / BUTTONS_COUNT;

for (int i = 0; i < BUTTONS_COUNT; i++) {
    UIButton *btn = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(sin(perAngle * i) + basePoint.x, cos(perAngle * i) + basePoint.y, Width, Height)];

    [self.View addSubView:btn];
}
```

I'm rotating this view around z-axis using CAAnimation so that it looks like all buttons are moving in circle when any button is tapped. The problem is I cannot decide by what angle to rotate so that every time only the tapped button comes to the top and not any other button.
Or any other totally different approach to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is WAAAAY too vague. You need to describe what you're trying to do in enough detail that somebody who isn't you knows what you're trying to do. You posted code that shows placing buttons in a circle, but did not show your rotation code. We need to see the code you need help with.

Comment: It seems to me that you need to know all of your buttons' current positions if you want to be able to rotate an arbitrary button to the top, and then tap again and then shift from the already-rotated position to the top.

Comment: You do not need to do the trigonometry or set the frame manually.  instead you place all of the buttons in the middle of the circle on top of each other and then you set the transform to counter rotate them, translate them then orbit the center point.  FYI in iOS the coordinates are cartesian scaled in Y by -1, ie the Y axis points downward, X axis points right, angle 0 is on the right, 90 is down, 180 is left and 270 is up.  rotations go clockwise.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playground that shows how to distribute the buttons in a circle using the transform (the starting angle is zero so just add whatever the current angle chould be and everythign will move).  Whatever is at 270 degrees or 1.5 pi will be on top of the circle.  You can animate the transforms to change the angle.  Note that I am setting the frames here because its a playground.  You can use constraints in your storyboard to achieve the same thing.

```
    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
    let buttonCount = 6
    for i in 0..<buttonCount {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.center = view.center
        button.setTitle("button \(i)", for: .normal)
        button.sizeToFit()
        view.addSubview(button)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: -2 * CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(buttonCount))
            .translatedBy(x: 100, y: 0)
            .rotated(by: 2 * CGFloat.pi * CGFloat(i) / CGFloat(buttonCount))
        button.transform = transform
    }

    PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```